# Windows - ftp.exe - Sending Multiple Files

Tags: windows, ftp, batch

How do you send multiple files using ftp.exe?

How do you send multiple files of the same file extension?

I tried using "mput", as the help for ftp.exe says that command is for sending multiple files, but I cannot figure it out, and I cannot find any official ftp.exe documentation.

I specifically want to send all of the text files in a single directory.  Here is what I tried (it only sends the alphabetically-first text file in the directory):

```
open url.com
username
password
cd Test
mput X:\*txt
```

This is the batch that calls the above text:

```
ftp.exe -s:name_of_text_file.txt
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but ftp.exe doesn't get much love on Windows as so few use it.  Can you use the command-line version that comes with winscp?

Comment: What is happening? Nothing is getting uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have it *almost* right. The only missing bit is `prompt`, which toggles interactive mode on/off. So it should be:

> open url.com
>   username
>   password
>   ***prompt***
>   cd Test
>   mput X:\*txt

Comment: I am pretty certain there needs to be a backslash("\") after the partition name in line 6.  Otherwise, it just looks in the directory of the script itself.  Also, your change did not work for me.  I tried "prompt", "prompt off", and "prompt on".  Still no joy.

Comment: about backslash - it was just a byproduct of markup, sorry. I have not noticed it got eaten. `Prompt` is just that - no on, off or anything else. What happens after first file is sent? You're left at ftp command prompt after script runs, so it should either copy all your files or ask you for each. Unless you redirect output, which you have not shown.

Comment: I am left with a cmd.exe window sitting open.  The output from ftp, starting at the prompt part, goes as follows: prompt >> Interactive mode Off . >> cd Test >> 250 CWD successful. "/Test" is current directory. >> put X:\\*txt >> 200 Port command successful >> 150 Opening data channel for file transfer. >> 226 Transfer OK >> 16 bytes sent in 0.xx seconds.  It ends with my cursor still in the ftp prompt, inside cmd.exe.

Comment: **>> put** X:\\*txt - that means you use `put` instead of `mput`! The effect will be just as you described - one (first expanded) file will be sent. Inspect your script, probably you have few versions of it and use incorrect one

Comment: yep, you got it. Somehow I never ended up with `mput` and `prompt` in the same file during my testing. Thanks.

Comment: Can this script be automated with the Windows Task Scheduler?  I am calling the .bat file with the Task Scheduler and receiving an error 0x2.  Perhaps I am supposed to call ftp.exe from the Task Scheduler and pass it the .txt file as a parameter, and not use the .bat?

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing.  No use for the .bat file.  In the Windows Task Scheduler, I made use of all three fields (1) Program, (2) Arguments, and (3) Run In.  Program = ftp.exe, Arguments = -s:name_of_file.txt, Run In = directory of the .txt file.

Comment: I've seen problems reported with TS and 0x2 (file not found) on Vista/W7. I cannot check it right now, but I would try two things: a) use `cmd /c drive:\path\yourbatchfile.bat`, if that still fails put absolute paths wherever you reference anything (script file included). Best to put this as a separate question on SE as comments are not meant for that